Saving changes on database before Unit of Work commit within MediatR CommandHandler
Project info
I'm using CQRS with MediatR and Unit of Work pattern. SignalR for real-time communication with client side.
What am I trying to achieve?
I have a Domain entity that represents the processing of an uploaded file to the API (extracting its content), called 'ProcessamentoArquivo' (something like 'file processing' in english). This entity has a property 'Status', an enum that shows the current progress of the extraction proccess.
    public enum EStatus
    {
        Aguardando, // Waiting
        Agendado, // Scheduled
        Processando, // Processing
        Finalizado, // Finished
        Erro // Error
    }

The process is currently executed inside a CommandHandler of MediatR in a BackgroundJob of Hangfire.
The objective is to update the property Status to it`s proper value in the middle of the execution of the command. That means changing the domain entity, commiting to the database and sending that info to the client via SignalR.
processamentoArquivo.UpdateStatus(EStatus.Processing);
//Update status and send signalR message.

//Rest of the command logic...

Problem and current solution
The problem is that I'm using the Unit of Work pattern that only commits changes in the end of the command execution. That means that if I send the info about 'status changed' via SignalR, in the database the value of the status column it's not updated yet, and that can lead me to consistency problems in some cases.
Since my UnitOfWork implementation is scoped I figured that creating a new service scope and calling a new MediatR CommandHandler using this new scope could be the solution to update the entity and database and send the SignalR message without saving the changes of the first command, but it seems a little wrong to do it that way.
How can I execute another command in a new scope without using the approach above, or there is no other way?
